# There should be a way to edit bounty text.

Tags: feature-request, bounty

I believe there should be a way to edit the optional bounty text.

It could happen that you simply forget to add important information about the bounty or you make a typo, etc.

Comment: Would you care to elaborate and support your request with argumentation?

Comment: @Lord_Farin I have added a bit. I'm not sure what else there could be to say. I don't think there could be any disadvantages of having this feature.

Comment: Too minor, in my opinion.

Comment: How about a comment? e.g., "I forgot to mention the primes have to be distinct."

Comment: @RobertSoupe The bounty text feature exists to have users fully contain the information about the bounty there -- it is better to have information about the bounty fully contained in the bounty text. Yes, you can edit the question or add a comment, but it is better to have all the information in the bounty text (this is why the bounty text feature exists in the first place).

Comment: @RobertSoupe and additionally, if you're adding a feature, then why not make it work perfectly. What I'm suggesting is a natural improvement. Whether it's worth taking the time to make it work is up to the moderators.

Comment: @quid I don't think it is reasonable to dismiss a suggestion just because it offers minor improvements. A lot of minor problems could add up to a pain to the user. And if it is not difficult to fix it, then why not.

Comment: Now I want to know: once the bounty is awarded, is there any way to look up its text? I've awarded two bounties, I can see what the question was, for how many points it was and to whom it was awarded (or auto-awarded, it seems in one case) but now I can't even see under what category I offered them (I think one was "to reward an existing answer" and the other was "canonical reference needed," but I can't remember for sure.

Comment: @RobertSoupe No, the text of the bounty is gone forever.

Comment: Every such "improvement" adds complexity for the users and developers, and ties up developers time that could be better used elsewhere. I think the request is overall not useful. Plus I doubt these texts are much read (if at all) by many users; if you want to add relevant information edit the post or post a comment.

Comment: The two times I've awarded a bounty, I've been given the impression that it's almost like turning matching keys on a submarine. You have to approach it carefully and thoughtfully. After you've entered the bounty text, you're given one last chance to change your mind. I think this is a point where you ask yourself if you're sure you want to do this, and if so, if you're happy with your bounty text.

Comment: @RobertSoupe I agree. The bounty text is more reflective of your choice to offer your reputation. Making the text unalterable symbolizes the fact that you can't undo your actions. (Not to make it a novel or anything)

Comment: Some other related posts on this meta [Cannot edit my bounty notice](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/20731) and [Is it possible to edit bounty messages?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/23213) More importantly, here is a feature request on Meta Stack Exchange: [Can we have a way to edit bounty custom message?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/112188):

Answer (score 2):

I agree! And would like help editing my bounty text from this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2878934/exploiting-a-diophantine-approximation-of-pi4-into-giving-a-series-of-ration). I typed $\pi/4$ but I obviously meant $\pi^4$. I am not sure why I need to bother a mod with this. I can see the other side of the issue: We don't want bounty hunters to have to deal with moving targets where the OP changes the objectives but it could be something like: OP can make changes and a few other users need to sign off on the change.

Anyway: It does happen but it's going to be hard to produce tons of evidence because bounty text is temporary but I suppose we could look at how often mods are bothered with this to try and generate more evidence that this is a worthwhile feature change. If it only happens once in a blue moon (As is suggested in the comments) I would think that it's not worth the change.