# Cannot edit my bounty notice

Tags: support, editing, bounty

I started a bounty [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1310342/elliptic-regularization-of-the-heat-equation), and placed the reason why as provided. However, I made several typos and I can't seem to edit the notice. I intended to say:

> $$L(Du,u_t,u,x,t)=\int_{U_T} e^{-c(\epsilon)t}\left (\frac{1}{2}|Du|^2 + \frac{1}{2} \epsilon | u_t|^2 \right ) \, dx dt$$

Is there a way to edit this? If not, can this be enabled in the future? In the meantime, I wrote this as a comment on that page informing readers of the typo.

**Edit:** Reposted my bounty with a notice sans typos. This meta question is now resolved.

Comment: [This Meta Stack Exchange feature request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/112188) may be of interest. It's a bit old, but no official word from SE about it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Bounty notices cannot be edited. Since the bounty was only five minutes old, I took the liberty of removing the bounty, so you can set up a new bounty with a notice without typos. Be careful and check the notice in an answer box preview before posting it.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. (Wow, I didn't know moderators can even undo the posting of bounties.)

Comment: There are some use cases for removing bounties. If a question needs to be closed prontissimo, for example, or if very soon after placing the bounty, a mistake was noticed ("Oops, I meant to place the bounty on question a), but took the wrong tab, now it's on question b)"). But it's an exceptional thing.