# How do I edit the description for a bounty after I have started a bounty

Tags: support, bounty

Is there a way to edit the text description I have put in for a bounty on a question?

I started a bounty, but made a math composition error in the text and don't know how to fix that as there is no edit button / link. Please help.

Comment: No, there's no way to fix this. Sorry.

Comment: Well, there sort of is. Since it's been just a few minutes, I've removed the bounty, so that you can start a new one without typos. But that's a once-only.

Comment: Thanks. I have fixed my bounty description and released a new bounty. 

I have two suggestions for improvement regarding this. (1) Please consider making the bounty description editing WYSIWYG (ie., with a preview similar to what is available for general question submission / editing where we can see the rendered version. (2) Please consider adding an edit link for the asker to allow editing the bounty text.

Comment: @vvgiri I remember such a thread on meta.SE (main), and it was probably status-deffered or declined. You may still add your own request there.

Comment: This seems to be a recurring topic: [Is it possible to edit bounty messages?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/23213), [There should be a way to edit bounty text.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/20176), [Cannot edit my bounty notice](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/20731), etc. You might want to upvote the corresponding feature request on [meta.se]: [Can we have a way to edit bounty custom message?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/112188) (It was marked [meta-tag:status-review] in February 2020 - which is a good sign, but I wouldn't be overly optimistic.)

Comment: wgiri - As for the preview ability, any time I write a comment with more than basic LaTeX, I jump down to the "Your Answer" edit box and compose it there. Once the LaTeX works I cut-and-paste it into the comment box. Also, there is a post on meta specifically for composing posts, where you can also save your work and come back to it later.

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC : I've upvoted all the Qs in the links given by Martin. It seems like a reasonable feature request. I'll remember your tip for the future while the feature req is under review.

Comment: Since a preview was mentioned, here are some [meta.se] posts I was able to find: [Markdown help and preview for bounty text](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/141587) and [Give some love to the Bounty tool](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/133640).

Comment: I agree that it seems like a reasonable feature request, so an upvote is a good idea. I've also heard stories of how math.se has had to fight for LaTeX support, and noticed the dates on those requests, so you should probably be prepared for a long feature request review.

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC FYI, the "... post on meta specifically for composing posts, where you can also save your work and come back to it later" you referred to is, I suspect, [Sandbox for drafts of long, complex posts](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4666/602049).

Comment: @JohnOmielan- Yep, that's the one. Thanks. Before I discovered that post I would quickly submit and then delete my LaTeX as an answer on an unrelated question if I was having some troubles with the live preview, but one time I wasn't fast enough on the delete and it picked up a down vote. Don't be dumb like me, folks - use the Sandbox.