# Is it possible to edit bounty messages?

Tags: support, mathjax, editing, bounty

The reason I ask is because I have a bounty question which is completely ruined as the sidebar covers the question. This has happened because of an error in the $\LaTeX$ in the bounty message which causes the question to stretch the width of page. [This is how bad it looks](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1777484/deriving-the-normalization-formula-for-associated-legendre-functions-stage-4).

If it is not possible to edit the bounty message does anyone have any idea how to tidy this up?

Or, can a moderator delete this question please and allow me to ask it again? (I can't delete a question once an answer has been given).

I ask of these things because *that* particular question was very important as it was the final question of $4$ previous connected questions.

Thank you.

Comment: Hopefully the bounty message can be edited by the powers that be.  However the formatting of the Question itself is in need of improvement.  Colored equations are not usually a good idea.  Using monospaced "code" blocks for emphasis is a bad idea (use `*` delimiters for emphasis text, or `__` delimiters for bold face text).  You have equations in the body of the Question that also run into the sidebar with my browser (Google Chrome 50).

Comment: I used the "Remove post notice" function available to moderators. I could not edit your bounty text, but that removal took care of the unrendered LaTeX and the resulting misplacement of components on the page. For the time being leaving your clarification in the question body will probably serve your purposes well. If you want further explanatory text added as a post notice, flag the post for our attention explaining what changes you want. I can also add another post notice (I think).

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen It looks much better now, thank you. You can tag this question as "Status-Complete" if you wish (I don't have access to do so). Best regards.

Comment: A related feature request on [meta.se]: [Can we have a way to edit bounty custom message?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/112188)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the worst case, [Moderators have a menu to remove and refund bounty offers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14591/how-can-we-close-questions-with-bounties). The first step is to flag the Question for Moderator attention (custom flag, explaining the problem with $\LaTeX$ formatting in the bounty message).

This came up in a recent discussion about [Why can't I delete a question with a bounty?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/22672/why-cant-i-delete-a-question-with-a-bounty-that-has-no-answers/22674#22674)  So your second proposed idea (deleting the Question and starting over) is unworkable.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it was helpful to know that moderators can refund/remove bounties (although not necessary in my case). Kindest regards.